# How to create a JSoup Document including JS?

Tags: javascript, java, jsoup

I create a JSoup Document which includes two `<script type="application/javascript">/* .. */</script>` elements.

The Issue: When I call `.html()` or `.toString()` JSoup will escape my JavaScript.

```
if (foo && bar)
```

gets

```
if (foo &amp;&amp; bar)
```

Is it possible to configure JSoup to ignore `<script>` Elements while escaping??

---

This is (basically) how I create my jsoup document.

```
final Document doc = Document.createShell("");
final Element head = doc.head();
head.appendElement("meta").attr("charset", "utf-8");
final String myJS = ...;
head.appendElement("script").attr("type", "application/javascript").text(myJS);
```

My current workaround is to replace a placeholder with `String.replace` on `.html()`. But this is kinda hacky.

```
head.appendElement("script").attr("type", "application/javascript").text("$MYJS$");
String s = doc.html();
s = s.replace("$MYJS$", myJS);
```

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 7):

The outerHtmlHead method can no longer be overridden.

This is what I use:

```
head
    .appendElement("script")
    .attr("type","text/javascript")
    .appendChild(new DataNode(getJavaScript(),""));
```

Comment: I would have expected .text() to work. I feel like this is a bug. .text() shouldn't do html encoding.